# Prove that $f$ is a bounded operator and $\|f\|=\dfrac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $f:\ell_{2}\longrightarrow{\mathbb R}$ with

$$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{x_n}{n^2}}$$

prove that $f$ is a bounded operator and $\|f\|=\dfrac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}$

Thanks!

Comment: Boundedness is trivial from Cauchy-Schwarz. The maximum can be derived by recalling that Cauchy-Schwarz is an equality when $x_n$ is linearly dependent to $1/n^2$. Assuming this, recall the value of $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/90.$ .

Comment: Bounded...I'll try thanks!

Comment: Probably the reason for the down-vote and the votes to close the question is that it is phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. By [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$|f(x)|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{x_n}{n^2}}\right|\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{1}{n^4}}\right)^{1/2}\|x\|.$$
Now [it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers) that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{1}{n^4}}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}.$$

Comment: If $A=1/n^2 $ . $|f(A)|=|A.A|=||A||^2=\frac{\pi^4}{90}=\frac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}|A|$ then $\dfrac{|f(A)|}{|A|}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}$ So $||f||\geq{\dfrac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}}$

Comment: @Franzz by CS it follows that $||f||\leq{\dfrac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}}$. Equality is attained for $(x_n)=(\dfrac{3\sqrt{10}}{n^2\pi^2})$

Comment: Oh! Thanks! RobertZ.

Answer (score 3):

If $\bigl\|(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr\|=1$, then$$\bigl|f\bigl((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr)\bigr|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{n^2}\right|\leqslant\bigl\|\bigl((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr)\bigr\|\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}}=\frac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}\bigl\|\bigl((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr)\bigr\|.$$So, $\|f\|\leqslant\frac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}$. In order to prover that $\|f\|=\frac{\pi^2}{3\sqrt{10}}$, compute $f\bigl(\bigl(\frac1{n^2}\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$.